# bash shell script failing to trigger action after comparing file sizes

Tags: shell, compare, filesize

i'm having trouble with a nested if-statement when comparing file sizes for the same file.

if the file size has *not* changed for x seconds, then do a file extension rename from .tmp to .pdf.

i'm using bash as my shell. the section that's giving me grievance starts in

```
if [ "$fsize1" -eq "$fsize2" ]; then
```

it seems that the script bypasses that section above completely. it doesn't even go inside the nested if-statement (ie the debugging echo statement "here" doesn't trigger)

any ideas on how to accomplish what i'm looking for? Most likely it's a syntax issue somewhere. thanks in advance for your inputs.

here's larger portion code i'm referring to:

```
if [ -f $TARGETDIR/*.tmp ]; then
  fsize=$(/usr/bin/ls -l | /usr/bin/grep *.tmp | /usr/bin/awk '{print $5}')
  fullfilename=$(/usr/bin/ls *.tmp)
  filenameonly=$(echo "$fullfilename" | sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//')
  fileextension=$(echo "$fullfilename" | sed 's/^.*\.//')
  echo $fullfilename
  echo $filenameonly
  echo $fileextension
  echo $fsize
  /usr/bin/sleep 5
  fsize2=$(/usr/bin/ls -l | /usr/bin/grep *.tmp | /usr/bin/awk '{print $5}')
  echo $fsize2
  if [ "$fsize1" -eq "$fsize2" ]; then
    /usr/bin/cat $TARGETDIR/$fullfilename > $TARGETDIR/$filenameonly.pdf
    echo "here"
    echo $fullfilename
    echo $filenameonly
    echo "file extension has been changed from tmp to pdf"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: then fsize1 must NOT equal fsize2. I notice your 2nd line of code creates a variable named `fsize`. Where does `fsize1` get created? Turn on shell debugging to see what values are being used for variables with `set -vx`. Good luck.

Comment: `then fsize1 must NOT equal fsize2` (sigh)...sometimes i don't know about myself man..thnx...